# Name the output file as value of element in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a XML source schema and an Flat file output schema.

Flat File Destination Schema:

```
Employee
  FName
  LName
```

I want the filename of output file as `{LName}_{DateAndTime}`. `DateAndTime` can be added by macros in BizTalk management console.
But can the value of `{LNmae}` be accessed somwhow?

I got an article to dynamically change the out filename in orchestration but it works for XMLTransit pipeline only.

https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2009/10/23/biztalk-training-customize-filename-dynamically-inside-orchestration/

Please let me know if it can be achieved in BizTalk.

Comment: This depends on how the orchestration works.. potentially you can pull the value of LName from the xml using XPath, or by promoting it so that it can be used in the orchestration.

Comment: @Arix  If you are only going to use a value from a XML payload in an Orchestration and not use it for routing, you should distinguish rather than promote, as promoting comes with extra overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an Orchestration or custom Pipeline Component, set the value of FILE.ReceivedFileName to your desired value: "Smith_02FEB19.txt".

Then you can use the %SourceFileName% Macro on the FILE or FTP Adapter to create the outfile with that name.

Comment: Also found an amazing article to do the same if you don't have the Orchestration or custom send pipeline in your project. You need to Promote the property which you'd like to send the value of for the output filename. read more about it here [geekswithblog](http://geekswithblogs.net/benny/archive/2007/03/09/108323.aspx)